# Unable to execute the else part of an if statment when conditon does not match in python

Tags: python, for-loop

When the Condition matches, It is printing the proper output as expected. But when the condition does not match the "if not found" part is not working.

here If condition checks the username and password both. If it satisfies, It executes the code below it, But when It does not match, It displays blank , I mean there is no Invalid Login printed , though It should get printed

```
passwd = {}
actual_user = {}
found = False

for row in prsnobj.result:
    actual_user[row[0]] = row[1]

    for i in range(1, 100):
        passwd[row[0]] = row[2]


for i in range(1, 100):

    if login == actual_user[i] and password == passwd[i]:
        found = True
        print "WELCOME !!" 

    if not found:
        print "<h4>Invalid Login</h4>"
```

Comment: You should use else instead of if not found: expression.

Comment: Can you try to execute the part inside the for loop?

Comment: Yes my inside for loop works complete fine

Comment: @Surinderツ: else doesnot work too.I tried that too

Comment: what errors you are getting? post full stacktrace in question.

Comment: blank screen. actaully i am working on cgi

Comment: try debugging line by line.

Comment: @Surinderツ: Tried that too..but everythign seems fime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this without a flag, using for/else:

```
for u, p in zip(actual_user.values(), passwd.values()):
    if login == u and password == p:
        print "WELCOME !!"
        break
else:
    print "<h4>Invalid Login</h4>"
```

But it may be better to use a dictionary:

```
logindb = {row[1]:row[2] for row in prsnobj.result}

if login in logindb and logindb[login] == password:
    print "WELCOME !!" 
else:
    print "<h4>Invalid Login</h4>"
```

Comment: in u and p ...unexpected values are coming

Comment: logindb = {row[1]:row[2] for row in prsnobj.result}
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax.       I am using python 2.5 Error of syntax near for loop

Comment: @user3003685, I don't have that version. What sort of unexpected values are you getting in the first version?

Comment: u and p contains 1,2 , 3 type values.....my row[0] contains Id, row[1] contains list of username and row[2] contains list of password. how do i access and compare each element  ?

Comment: @user3003685, I think I just fixed that problem

Answer (score 0):

The relevant part of your code could be more simple expressed as this:

```
if a == 1:
    found = True

if not found:
    print "not found"
```

The problem with this is that you **never set found to false**. Even if a is not equal to 1, found is still true from the last time you found something.

So the solution is something like this:

```
found = False

if a == 1:
    found = True

if not found:
    print "not found"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in prsnobj.result:

    logindb = {row[1]:row[2]}
    #print logindb

    if login in logindb and logindb[login] == password:
        print "Welcome"
        break 
    else:
        print "Invalid"
        break
```